# Can't clear input text in material-ui Aucocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new in reacting and Material-UI, and I'm trying to add dynamic places to a list as in [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocompleteplace-x1cd9).

When I add element by clicking on the button (+), the input text keeps the last value entered.

Please, do you have any idea how to clear text input after add?

Comment: Is that codesandbox *your* code that isn't working, or is it a non-working sandbox demo that you're trying to work from?

Comment: It's my code that isn't working.

Comment: Seems your logic changes the `Autocomplete` component from uncontrolled to controlled after you start typing. Try moving some of the of the input logic out of your `AutocompletePlace` into `places`, or vise versa. Essentially the same component that handles the "add" button needs to also handle setting the value back to an empty string.

Comment: I tried this idea, it didn't work.